# Outlook JS Add-in: Credentials from Token (On-Premise Exchange, Not OAuth)

Tags: service, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, office-js

Because of a limitation in message size in the Office API, I am trying to build a service that:

- Office client gets identity token (getCallbackTokenAsync)
- Posts message including identity token to service
- Service creates new new Exchange Service, with new Token Credential

Limitations:

- The EWS server is on premise, and it is currently not possible to use OAuth
- I'm currently using this as a RESTful service

I have tried getUserIdentityToken, but that is not useful for credentials.

Office JS call

```
var _appName;
var _mailbox;
var _emailAddress;
var _itemId;
var _identityToken;
var _ewsUrl;

    app.initialize();
    _mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
    var item = _mailbox.item;
    _itemId = item.itemId;
    _ewsUrl = _mailbox.ewsUrl;
    _emailAddress = _mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress;

    function MakeRequest(serviceUrl, callType, format) {

        _mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.error) {
                app.showNotification(_appName, "Error getting Use Identity Token: " + asyncResult.error.message);
            }
            else {

                _identityToken = asyncResult.value;

                var correctedItemId = _itemId.replace("+", "_");
                var request = { ItemId: correctedItemId, UserEmailAddress: _emailAddress, UserIdentityToken: _identityToken, EwsUrl: _ewsUrl, AudienceUrl: _audUrl, ReturndNewId: false };

                $.ajax({
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: serviceUrl,
                    type: callType,
                    data: JSON.stringify(request),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: format,
                    success: function (asyncResultSuccess) {
                        LogResult(asyncResultSuccess.statusText);
                        //app.showNotification(_appName, asyncResultSuccess.statusText);
                    },
                    error: function (asyncResultError) {
                        LogResult(asyncResultError.statusText);
                        //app.showNotification(_appName, asyncResultError.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Server Side Credential:

```
    void LoadSimple()
    {
        try
        {
            service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1)
            {
                Credentials = new TokenCredentials(RequestProperties.UserIdentityToekn),
                Url = new Uri(RequestProperties.EwsUrl)
            };
            ReturnProps = new EwsReturnItem();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(string.Format("{0}: {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

Server Side Forward Message:

```
    public EwsReturnItem Forward(string toRecipient, string ccRecipient, string subjectPrepend, string bodyText)
    {
        try
        {
            var correctedId = CorrectItemId(RequestProperties.ItemId);
            EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, correctedId, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent, ItemSchema.Subject));
            ResponseMessage forwardMessage = email.CreateForward();
            forwardMessage.Subject = String.Format("{0}{1}", subjectPrepend, email.Subject);
            forwardMessage.ToRecipients.Add(toRecipient);
            forwardMessage.CcRecipients.Add(ccRecipient);
            forwardMessage.BodyPrefix = bodyText;

            ...snip


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(string.Format("{0}: {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message));
            return new EwsReturnItem() { StatusText = ex.Message };
        }
    }
```

It fails as unauthorized on this line:

```
EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, correctedId, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent, ItemSchema.Subject));
```

Comment: Thanks for writing to us. We will need more details to investigate this issue further. Which outlook client are you using Windows/Mac/Web? What is the outlook version?

Comment: Versions: exchange server = 2016, Outlook = 2016 (proplus) v1808

Comment: Some questions/comments: 1) Where are you getting the URL that you are sending your EWS Request to? 2) The Token is only valid for the currentItem. I'm not sure what CorrectItemId() in your code, but is it possible that you are using the wrong ItemId? 3) Forward won't work here (though that is after you are seeing failure). Only GetItem and GetAttachment are allowed.

Comment: (1) - I've updated the code for the JS to show how the item ID and the EWS URL are derived. (2) The code is getting the current item along with the token, which should now be visible form the code. (3) This decision to try writing a service is because of limitation in the message size of the Office JS (1 Mb), and based on what you wrote, is it possible for me to get the item, then send the mime content back via the ajax call, in that way avoiding the JS library limitation of 1 Mb?

Comment: In your code you appear to be modifying the ItemId, I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: I modified the id to pass it to the service then converted it back. There was problem with  the + character - i might have had an issue writing the escape - so converted to an underscore, then converted it back at the service level.

Comment: The 1MB limit is on the size of the request, so even if you got the message contents server side, you would not be able to send the message client size (as the message would be >1MB)

Comment: Understood. I might have to open a ticket, but wondering without REST and being on prem, how can I performed these actions server side? account with impersonation right. Can windows authentication work, on prem using client credentials? If so, what kind of service do I need?

Comment: I'm not well versed in using EWS, but the following docs should be of help to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange